# Draw horizontal divider in winforms

Tags: .net, winforms

In the standard windows installer there is a divider between the control buttons on the bottom and the main part of the form. Does anyone know how this would be done in winforms/.net? I've tried fiddling around with the border settings on Panel controls etc, but haven't been able to get the same result...

[image]

Comment: While this is a duplicate, the accepted answer here is far better than any in the original question.

Comment: When one watches a video game and goes back to search the toolbar for such a primitive control and you don't find it, you then know immediately that time travel is possible. Hard to believe what Microsoft people thinks!

Answer (score 465, accepted):

I used Spy++ to figure this out a while ago and discovered that it's just a standard Win32 Static control -- the equivalent of the WinForms Label.  Steps for getting the same effect:

1. Add a Label control to your form.
2. Set Label Text to empty.
3. Set BorderStyle to Fixed3D.
4. Set AutoSize to false.
5. Set Height to 2 (most easily accomplished by typing 2 into the Size/Height field under Label Properties).

Comment: Perfect.
But how to change the color of this line?

Comment: works for horizontal divider as well

Comment: You can change border style to Fixed Single then you can change the background color.

Comment: I want a Line by with 100% , I don't set static width . how can I do this?

Comment: @osmanRahimi I'm assuming you mean when you resize the form, you want the divider to resize as well?  Add Right to the Anchor property on the Label (so Anchor should be Left,Top,Right) and it will automatically resize to preserve whatever margin exists between the line and the side of the container.  If you want no margin, resize the line to fill the full width of the designer.  If you want margins, position the line in the designer with the desired margins.  These will be preserved by Anchor Left/Right.

Comment: I have to wonder what M$ was thinking when they removed the Line object.

Comment: To give the line a colour, the background colour can be set without changing the border style (though you might have to increase the height a bit).

Comment: I think if you want the exact two pixel high line with the inset effect with different colors, the simplest way would just be to build a custom control that draws the lines in OnPaint.