# Inheriting System.Windows.Forms.Label Does Not Respect AutoSize Override

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to use a label to create a custom Separator control by overriding the properties as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527026/the-best-way-to-draw-a-line-in-windows-form-c-sharp).

Everything seems to be working except that the control does not seem to respect the AutoSize property.  The property is set to false, but when the control is drawn, it acts as though AutoSize is set to true and it sets the width to 2, regardless of what I change the size to.  What am I missing here?

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms.Controls
{
    public class Separator : Label
    {
        [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public override bool AutoSize { get => base.AutoSize; set => base.AutoSize = value; }

        [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public override Size MaximumSize { get => new(0, 2); }

        [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public override Size MinimumSize { get => new(2, 2); }

        [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public override BorderStyle BorderStyle { get => BorderStyle.Fixed3D; }

        [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public override string Text { get => string.Empty; }

        [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public override ContentAlignment TextAlign { get => base.TextAlign; set => base.TextAlign = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you overriding it? why use a label in the first place?

Comment: Is the width supposed to be fixed to 1 pixel?

Comment: Decorate the class with `[ToolboxItem(true)]`, otherwise the Designer will use [the default `AutoSizeToolboxItem`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Label.cs,42), which sets the Property value to `true`

Comment: BTW, if you really don't want your Users to tamper with some properties, add a custom Designer that removes the properties entirely, as show, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74935646/7444103), instead of trying to hide them from the PropertyGrid. Those properties are still accessible in code

Comment: @DanielA.White I use the separator many times throughout the application and find it much easier to just add a custom control rather than setting all of the properties for each instance.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you Jimi, that worked perfectly and answered my questions as to why it was not working!

Answer (score 1):

Another take on this would be to set the base class properties and null out the setters in the subclass. Almost the reverse of the way you're going about it.

[image: form with separators]

```
public class Separator : Label
{
    public Separator()
    {
        base.Height = 2;
        base.AutoSize = false;
        base.MaximumSize = new(0,2);
        base.MinimumSize = new(2,2);
        base.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    }
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public override bool AutoSize{ get => base.AutoSize; set { } }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public override Size MaximumSize { get => base.MaximumSize; set { } }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public override Size MinimumSize { get => base.MinimumSize; set { } }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public override BorderStyle BorderStyle { get => BorderStyle.Fixed3D; set { } }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public override string? Text { get => base.Text; set { } }
}
```

---

**Main Form**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Controls.Add(new Separator
        {
            Location = new Point(50, 100),
            Width = 100,
        });
        Controls.Add(new Separator
        {
            Location = new Point(50, 150),
            Width = 200,
        });
        Controls.Add(new Separator
        {
            Location = new Point(50, 200),
            Width = 300,
        });
    }
}
```