# Is there something like a horizontal line (i.e. <hr>) that can be used for C# Message Box?

Tags: c#, html, messagebox, horizontal-line

For example instead of doing the `("\n-----------------");` for a `MessageBox.Show();` function, is there an in-build horizontal line generator similar to the HTML `<hr>`?

Comment: NO.............

Comment: Any suggestions on what can I use to make my MessageBox look a little more organized in sections?  I'm just new at this C# coding and still learning it.

Comment: Create your own form and show it as modal....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A messagebox is a simple element for showing plain text. It does not have much design features.

However you can easily create a new form, put in its text and show it using `Form.ShowDialog`. Now you can add any design-element you want by chosing it in the toolbox, e.g. by using a [2px label as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296110/draw-horizontal-divider-in-winforms).

You could also implement the syntax you know from `MessageBox` by using a static method:

```
public class CustomMessageBox : Form
{
    private readonly static instance = new CustomMessageBox();
    private DialogResult result = DialogResult.No;

    private CustomMessageBox()
    {
        btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        btnCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.AcceptButton = btnOK;
        this.CancelButton = btnCancel;
    }
    public static DialogResult Show(string text)
    {
        return instance.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a form, and send the message in your constructor or in function. And set the available buttons that you want to see...
That way you can handle the response-buttons